# 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute

Tags: django

I have a model defined like this:

```
class UserDetail(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_index=True, unique=True, related_name='details')
    favourites = models.ManyToManyField(Article, related_name='favourited_by', blank=True)
```

And I'm trying to do something like this:

```
article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=id)
request.user.details.favourites.add(article)
```

Why isn't it working?

I'm getting this error:

> 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'favourites'

I guess `details` isn't the right type, but why isn't it? And how can I perform a query like that?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

When you access `user.details`, it accesses the backreference of the `UserDetail.user` foreign key.  The foreign Key itself doesn't specify that a `User` can only have one `UserDetail`, so django gives you a `RelatedManager`, which you can filter and query just like a regular `Manager`.  So you do the  same things to it that you do to your `.objects` managers.  You can ask for `user.details.all()`, `user.details.filter()`, `user.details.get()`, and so on, which will either give you a queryset, an object, or an exception,depending on the method and the results.

Comment: Oh! That makes so much more sense now. I guess it was obvious to *me* that a user only has one `UserDetail`, but I suppose that's not specified anywhere. Thank you.

Comment: If you changed your model so that instead of using a ForeignKey, you used a OneToOneField, you would be able to do exactly like you expected. OneToOneFields are like ForeignKeys except that since their is only one related object, Django will give you access to the object directly rather than through a related manager.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield

Answer (score 15):

Try

```
request.user.details.get().favourites.add(article)
```

This assumes the UserDetail object already exists for that user, otherwise `get()` will raise an exception.