# How to join 3 tables in query with Django, combined select related and prefetch_related

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have tree models

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)


class Product(models.Model):
    description = = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products')


class Inventory(models.Model):
     userReservation = models.ForeignKey(User)
     Product=models.ForeignKey(Product related_name='products_reservation')
     Quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to get all product by category, with quantity registered in inventory, for the user and the product

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Corbata",
"products": [{
        "id": 10,
        "description": "shoes",
        "quantitybyInventory": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "description": "shirt",
        "quantitybyInventory": 1
    }]}
```

I have a view with this class 
views.py

```
 class inventoryList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

queryset = Category.objects.prefetch_related('products')
serializer_class = CategorybyProductSerializer
def get_object(self):
    queryset = self.queryset()
    obj = get_object_or_404(queryset)
    return obj
```

And my serializer

```
class CategorybyProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
products = ProductSerializer(many=True)

class Meta:
    model = Category
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'products')

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ('id', 'description')
```

but I can not show the amount of the inventory table

this query just show me it

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Corbata",
"products": [{
        "id": 10,
        "description": "shoes"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "description": "shirt"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: can you add `ProductSerializer` class?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

I use [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield), and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1823965/10071876)

```
class ProductbyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    quantitybyInventory = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_quantitybyInventory(self, product):
        return product.products_reservation.filter(userReservation = self.context['request'].user).count()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'description', 'quantitybyInventory')
```

Comment: OP asked for combinations of select_related and prefetch_related, likely they're looking for query optimizations